# Basic formula to calculate decimal between two numbers

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I'm having a brain fart and need help with a basic formula.

```
if (d >= 0.1) {
   scale = 0.1
} else if (d <= 0.004) {
   scale = 1;
}
```

How can I set the value of scale to somewhere between 0.1 and 1 if the value of `d` is somewhere between 0.1 and 0.004?

Comment: You mean _relatively_?

Comment: So `0.004` should return `0.1` and `0.1` should return `1`?

Comment: i can’t ever remember the formula but i know there’s a few answers already regarding this .. search along the lines of ‘mapping/re-mapping a range’ or ‘clamping a range’

Comment: It needs to be a linear scale between the two numbers. So if `d` is closer to 0.1 `scale` would be closer to `0.1`, if `d` is closer to 0.004 `scale` will be closer to 1

Comment: @NiklasHigi Correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `else` statement to handle the numbers between `0.004` and `0.1`:

```
// ...
else {
    scale = 1 - (d - 0.004) * (1 - 0.1) / (0.1 - 0.004);
}
```

Or you can do the whole thing in one go:

```
var scale = 1 - (Math.max(Math.min(d, 1), 0.004) - 0.004) * (1 - 0.1) / (0.1 - 0.004);
```

Answer (score 2):

The scaling should look like this:

```
scale = 1 - (1 - 0.1)*(d - 0.004)/(0.1 - 0.004)
```

or more simply

```
scale = 1 - 9.375*(d - 0.004)
```

For example, if `d = 0.05`, then `scale = 0.56875`.

Comment: There's a `=` in the variable after declaration making it invalid

Comment: @jskidd3 Right. It was intended as a simplification of the formula, not as code to be run.

Comment: No worries I did think that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from the comments, this is the pattern for your calculation. `dRange` is the range of d values. The input values are limited to also restrict the output.

***Note:** The input values `d` are first restricted, so that we have 2 absolute 'scales' that we can mirror: `dRange` and `scaleRange`, and their corresponding min- and max-values.*

***Note:** The inverted `scaleRange`, where `1` (max value) is to the left, and `0.1` (min value) is to the right:*

```
           0.004                   <-- dRange -->                          0.1
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~|--------------------------------------------------------------|~~~~~~~~~~~~

In: ~~~d~~~~~d----------------------d---------------------------------------d-----d------
       |     |                      |                                       |     |
       ----->|                      |                                       |<----
             |                      |                                       |
Limited:   [d,d]--------------------d-------------------------------------[d,d]
             |                      |                                       |
Out:       [x,x]--------------------x-------------------------------------[x,x]

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~|--------------------------------------------------------------|~~~~~~~~~~~~
             1                  <-- scaleRange -->                         0.1
```

That's some of the more complex logic that deserves a slightly more declarative approach. I came up with the following to implement the scenario above. Further explanation is in the code comments:

```js
// The minimum and maximum values for d - also the 'input'
const minDValue = 0.004;
const maxDValue = 0.1;

// The minimum and maximum values for scale - also the 'output'
const minScaleValue = 0.1;
const maxScaleValue = 1;

// Absolute ranges for d and scale:
const dRangeAbs = maxDValue - minDValue;
const scaleRangeAbs = maxScaleValue - minScaleValue;

// restricts the value of d if it exceeds the bounds:
// 'minDValue <= d <= maxDValue'
function restrictD(d) {
    return Math.max(minDValue, Math.min(maxDValue, d));
}

// Calculate the absolute scale value for a certain d-value.
function scaleForDValue(d) {

    // First, restrict the input. If not restricted the input 'scale' is
    // not accurate, and we can not determine the corresponding scale.
    d = restrictD(d);

    // Determine how far (as fraction of 1) the d-value sits along
    // the absolute d-range:
    const dProgressFraction = (d - minDValue) / dRangeAbs;

    // Use the d-progress-fraction to add a corresponding relative
    // progress value for the scale-'scale'. Because the scale is
    // inverted, we subtract the progress from the max-value this
    // time.
    const calculatedScale = maxScaleValue - (dProgressFraction * scaleRangeAbs);

    // Restrict calculated value to prevent rouding error.
    return Math.min(maxScaleValue, Math.max(minScaleValue, calculatedScale));
}

// Log some values!
const log = (val, info) => console.log({ d: val, scale: scaleForDValue(val), info });

log(minDValue, 'this is the min d-value');
log(minDValue - 1, 'this is a too low d-value');
log(maxDValue, 'this is the max d-value');
log(maxDValue + 1, 'this is a too high d-value');

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    log(minDValue + Math.random() * dRangeAbs, 'A random d-value');
}
```